# Global Windows Software Updater

Tags: windows, updates, automatic-update, software-update

Is there a way like in Linux how you update ALL your software a way to also update ALL your Windows software at the same time? Or just to check and see which applications are outdated and need to be manually updated.

I know mac has MacUpdater for example and Linux uses Yum and Apt-get.

Comment: Yum and Apt only update what was installed through them.  It does not update software that wasnt.  I have plenty of Linux software packages that have to be updated manually.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several software for this, for example.

- [UpdateChecker - FileHippo](http://www.filehippo.com/updatechecker/)(Free, works on Windows 8, 7, Vista, XP)

  [image]

---

- [Update Notifier](http://cleansofts.org/view/update-notifier.html)(Free, works on Windows XP, Vista, 7)

  [image]

---

- [SUMo](http://www.kcsoftwares.com/index.php?sumo) (**Software Update Monitor**)

  [image]

---

Answer (score 4):

Scott Hanselman has an nice post on [Chocolatey](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IsTheWindowsUserReadyForAptget.aspx). Don't know any more about it than what I read there, but it does seem similar to `apt-get` and friends.